# Implement a WebSocket Server in PyGame to control objects via a HTML WebSocket Client

Tags: python, websocket, pygame

### General idea

I successfully configured a [raspberry pi as an access point](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/computers/configuration.html#setting-up-a-routed-wireless-access-point) such that I can connect via WIFI with my mobile phone or laptop. Now, I would like to run PyGame on the raspberry pi, which is connected to a screen, and control objects in a game via a mobile phone or laptop that is connected to the raspberry pi.

In the following, I provide simple working examples first and then show what did not work.

### Testing the WebSocket Server worked

To provide some content to the clients, I installed an nginx server on the raspberry pi. When I open a browser with the IP address of the raspberry pi (192.168.4.1), the index page appears.

Then, to test a WebSocket Server, I wrote a simple python script based on the [websockets package](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```py
import websockets
import asyncio

# handler processes the message and sends "Success" back to the client
async def handler(websocket, path):
    async for message in websocket:
        await processMsg(message)
        await websocket.send("Success")

async def processMsg(message):
    print(f"[Received]: {message}")

async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(handler, "192.168.4.1", 6677):
        await asyncio.Future() # run forever

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I tested the server by setting up an HTML page, which connects to the WebSocket Server via a Javascript file and implements a button to send a string to the server:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WebSocket Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/client.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h2>WebSocket Test</h2>
      <input type="button" name="send" value="Send Hello!" onClick="sendHello()">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the client.js file:

```js
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.4.1:6677/");

socket.onopen = function(e) {
  console.log("[open] Connection established");
  console.log("[send] Sending to server");
  socket.send("Web connection established")
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log(`[message] Data received from server: ${event.data}`);
};

socket.onclose = function(event) {
  if (event.wasClean) {
    console.log(`[close] Connection closed cleanly, code=${event.code} reason=${event.reason}`);
  } else {
    console.log('[close] Connection died!')
  }
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
  console.log(`[error] ${error.message}`);
};

function sendHello() {
  console.log("[send] Sending to server");
  socket.send("Hello!");
};
```

With these simple example files I could successfully establish a persistent connection and exchange data between server and client.

### Adding the WebSocket Server to PyGame did not work

To test the WebSocket Server with PyGame, I set up a simple game only displaying a blue circle:

```py
# import and init pygame library
import pygame
pygame.init()

# screen dimensions
HEIGHT = 320
WIDTH = 480

# set up the drawing window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([WIDTH,HEIGHT])

# run until the user asks to quit
running = True
while running:
    # did the user close the window
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # fill the background with white
    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    # draw a solid blue circle in the center
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0,0,255), (int(WIDTH/2),int(HEIGHT/2)), 30)

    # flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

The game is running as it should, displaying a blue circle on a white background.

The problem is that when I want to add the WebSocket Server to the game, either one is blocking the execution of the other part, i.e., I can only run the game without an active server or I can run the WebSocket server but the game is not showing up. For example, putting the WebSocket server in front of the game loop like this

```py
# WS server
async def echo(websocket, path):
    async for message in websocket:
        msg = message
        print(f"[Received] {message}")
        await websocket.send(msg)

async def server():
    async with websockets.serve(echo, "192.168.4.1", 6677):
        await asyncio.Future()

asyncio.ensure_future(server())
```

or including the game-loop inside the server:

```py
async def server():
    async with websockets.serve(echo, "192.168.4.1", 6677):
        #await asyncio.Future()

        # set up the drawing window
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode([WIDTH,HEIGHT])

        # run until the user asks to quit
        running = True
        while running:
            #pygame code goes here
```

By an extensive Google search I figured out that PyGame and the asyncio package (websockets is based on asyncio) cannot simply work together as I have to somehow take care of, both, the asyncio-loop and the game-loop manually.

I hope someone can help me dealing with this problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a colleague of mine I figured out the solution to get Pygame running including a Websockets server and responding to buttons pressed on mobile clients. The important point is to run the Websockets server in a different thread and properly handle events.

Here is the code of **server.py**. I changed the IP address to local host (127.0.0.1) in order to test the code on my laptop.

```py
import websockets
import asyncio
import pygame

IPADDRESS = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 6677

EVENTTYPE = pygame.event.custom_type()

# handler processes the message and sends "Success" back to the client
async def handler(websocket, path):
    async for message in websocket:
        await processMsg(message)
        await websocket.send("Success")

async def processMsg(message):
    print(f"[Received]: {message}")
    pygame.fastevent.post(pygame.event.Event(EVENTTYPE, message=message))

async def main(future):
    async with websockets.serve(handler, IPADDRESS, PORT):
        await future  # run forever

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The important part here is the method `pygame.fastevent.post` to trigger a Pygame event.

Then, in **game.py** the server is initiated in a different thread:

```py
# import and init pygame library
import threading
import asyncio
import pygame
import server


def start_server(loop, future):
    loop.run_until_complete(server.main(future))

def stop_server(loop, future):
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(future.set_result, None)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = loop.create_future()
thread = threading.Thread(target=start_server, args=(loop, future))
thread.start()

pygame.init()
pygame.fastevent.init()

# screen dimensions
HEIGHT = 320
WIDTH = 480

# set up the drawing window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([WIDTH, HEIGHT])

color = pygame.Color('blue')
radius = 30
x = int(WIDTH/2)

# run until the user asks to quit
running = True
while running:
    # did the user close the window
    for event in pygame.fastevent.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == server.EVENTTYPE:
            print(event.message)
            color = pygame.Color('red')
            x = (x + radius / 3) % (WIDTH - radius * 2) + radius

    # fill the background with white
    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    # draw a solid blue circle in the center
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, (x, int(HEIGHT/2)), radius)

    # flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

print("Stoping event loop")
stop_server(loop, future)
print("Waiting for termination")
thread.join()
print("Shutdown pygame")
pygame.quit()
```

Be careful to properly close the thread running the Websockets Server when you want to exit Pygame!

Now, when you use the HTML file including the client.js script I posted in the question, the blue circle should change its color to red and move to the right every time you press the "Send hello" button.

I hope this helps everyone who is trying to setup an online multiplayer game using Pygame.